Quarkus: Get resolved issuer from OIDC-tenant
I need to know the issuer of an OIDC-tenant, i.e. I don't want to specify it myself in the configuration, but I want to read the introspected value. I know it is resolved at the time I need it, because it is available in TenantConfigBean->TenantConfigContext->OidcProvider. But it is not accessible for me, because the member is package-private there.
The reason I need this is that I want to use it in a CustomTenantResolver to select the tenant by the issuer of the token. This seems to be a very useful use case for me.
Is there a way to get the resolved values from OidcProvider in my application? I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation.
Thanks in advance.

Inject quarkus.oidc.OidcConfigurationMetadata, it will give you a discovered or configured issuer

I already tried that, but I want to use it in a io.quarkus.oidc.TenantConfigResolver, and then I get a ContextNotActiveException.
What I want to do is basically: In the io.quarkus.oidc.TenantConfigResolver, I read the token from the authorization-header. From the token, I get the issuer. And then I want to loop over the configured tenants to find the one with the same issuer-entry.
At the moment, I hard-coded the issuer for the configured tenants. So I'm able to get it from OidcConfig. But IMHO it would be cleaner if I could get the resolved one, so I don't need to configure it.

Oh, now I see that starting with Quarkus 3.15, there already is a config for that: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-configuration-properties-reference#quarkus-oidc_quarkus-oidc-resolve-tenants-with-issuer

@SimonWick Oh I see, I did not understand the question then, right Quarkus now ships a default tenant resolver which will find the right tenant automatically given the token issuer
